# What's the browsing motivation of Tinder style E commerce apps

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, e-commerce

I'm working on an ecommerce app that uses a tinder like approach to browse products.

Similar to these
http://fashionista.com/2014/05/tinder-for-fashion-apps

There's definitely a different line of thought for both kinds of swiping/browsings. one where the user is given a yes/no choice and the other where user is given many choices to pick from.

how does this ultimately effect conversions? the user will definitely end up with a bigger 'yes list' than a if the users added to cart with conventional browsing, while while might be something they like but will not necessarily buy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle of tinder comes from card sorting techniques. As you stated in your question, in first iteration, user will have a big "yes list". In next iterations, passively, you can divide that bigger yes list into smaller parts. In such workflow, the priority items can be found and new counter-offers can be generated for convincing user.

In the end, you can hypothetically know what user wants more which can be accepted as a valuable information. I think that card sorting mechanism will work if user;

- motivated to check all available options (not quick decision giver)
- decisions are shaped by what is available
- is willing to bind himself to eco-system rather than checking multiple eco-systems.